# Adding tasks to todo list

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I've been having this problem for a very long time and no one has been able to resolve it yet... When I try to add a new task on my website I get the message "POST /templates/todo" Error (404): "Not found" and cannot find what is wrong with the code. Can anyone help me figure it out (and give me a solution please)? I'm beginning to think that maybe it is an issue with my for loop, but I'm not sure. It was done on cs50 ide software. Thank you so much in advance.

**application.py code**

```
def todo():
    if "todos" not in session:
        session["todos"] = []
    return render_template('todo.html', todos=session["todos"])
        
@app.route('/clear')
def clear():
    return redirect("/todolist")
    session["todos"] = []
        
@app.route('/add', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add():
    if request.method == "GET":
       return render_template("add.html")
    else:
        todo = request.form.get("task")
        session["todos"].append(todo)
        return redirect("/todo")
```

**add.html code**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
          Add a New Task :)
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class = "aligncenter">
            <img class = "img1" src = "/static/images/logocarol.jpg" alt = "Logo" height = "200" width = "550"/>    
        </h1>
        <h1 class="centergeneral fontsize">
            Add any goals, dreams and aspirations you might have here:
        </h1>
        <form class="aligncenter" action="/todolist" method="POST"> 
            <input id="task" name="task" type="text" placeholder="New Task :)">   
            <input id="submit" type="submit" disabled>
        </form>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = function(){
                if (document.querySelector('#task').value === ''){
                    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
                } else {
                     document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
                }
            }
        </script>

        <form action="index">
            <button type="submit" id = "back" class="btn btn-info margin"> BACK TO HOMEPAGE </button> <br> <br>
        </form>
        <form action="/todo">
            <button type="submit" id = "back" class="btn btn-outline-info margin"> BACK TO TO DO LIST </button> <br> <br>
        </form>
    </body>
```

**todo.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
          To Do List! :)
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class = "aligncenter">
            <img class = "img1" src = "/static/images/logocarol.jpg" alt = "Logo" height = "200" width = "550"/>    
        </h1>
        <h1 class="fonts centergeneral"> To Do List </h1>
        <h2 class="fs-4 centergeneral"> What I Want to Achieve: </h2> <br>
        <ul class="listcenter">
            <script>
            {%for todo in todos%}
                <li> {{ todo }} <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> </li> 
            {%end for%}
            </script>
        </ul>
        
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info margin" href = "add"> Add a New Task</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href = "clear"> Clear Tasks </a> <br>
        <div class="backbuttons">
        <form action = "index">
            <button type="submit" id = "back" class="btn btn-info"> BACK TO HOMEPAGE </button> <br> <br>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically **404-Error-code** describes that particular page or resource/route does not exist in your application. In your case also the same thing happened,  because as per my knowledge **you should declare a routes for every method which will be executed while routing.**

**finally:**

You missed the route declaration of `/todo`

`@app.route('/todo')`

Try again,By adding this line. I hope it will help to you **:**)